# File Icon's current overlay

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, icons, shell32

I have been scouring the internet for about 5 hours now and i'll be damned if i can find the answer to this. I have found this question unanswered in multiple places along my journey.

I'm willing to work with any language that can yield information relating even remotely to a files current icon overlay. Images below demonstrate the overlay i'm talking about.

[image: Synchronizing]

[image: Complete]

Comment: `SHGetFileInfo` with the `SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX` flag can give you the overlay index, but I don't think there's any way to relate that back to a specific overlay handler. Overlay indices can be different on a per-process basis since it depends on the order the handler DLLs are loaded/invoked.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure GetOverlayIconInfo(const AFileName: UnicodeString; out AIconFileName: UnicodeString; out AIconIndex: Integer);
const
  sShellIconOverlayIdentifiers = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers';
  sShell32 = 'shell32.dll';
  sImageres = 'imageres.dll';

  procedure RegCheck(AStatus: DWORD);
  begin
    if AStatus = ERROR_SUCCESS then Exit;
    SetLastError(AStatus);
    RaiseLastOSError;
  end;

  function GetNextOverlayIconHandlerName(AKey: HKEY; AIndex: Integer): UnicodeString;
  var
    Status: DWORD;
    Len: DWORD;
  begin
    Len := 256;
    while True do
      begin
        SetLength(Result, Len - 1);
        Status := RegEnumKeyExW(AKey, AIndex, PWideChar(Result), Len, nil, nil, nil, nil);
        case Status of
          ERROR_SUCCESS:
            begin
              SetLength(Result, Len);
              Exit;
            end;
          ERROR_MORE_DATA: Len := Len * 2;
          ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS:
            begin
              Result := '';
              Exit;
            end
        else
          RegCheck(Status);
        end;
      end;
  end;

  function GetOverlayIconHandlerCLSID(AKey: HKEY; const AName: UnicodeString): TCLSID;
  var
    Key: HKEY;
    Status: DWORD;
    Len: DWORD;
    Size: DWORD;
    CLSID: UnicodeString;
  begin
    RegCheck(RegOpenKeyExW(AKey, PWideChar(AName), 0, KEY_READ, Key));
    try
      Len := 256;
      while True do
        begin
          SetLength(CLSID, Len);
          Size := Len * SizeOf(WideChar);
          Status := RegQueryValueExW(Key, nil, nil, nil, PByte(PWideChar(CLSID)), @Size);
          case Status of
            ERROR_SUCCESS:
              begin
                SetLength(CLSID, (Size div SizeOf(WideChar)) - 1);
                Result := StringToGUID(CLSID);
                Exit;
              end;
            ERROR_MORE_DATA: Len := (Size div SizeOf(WideChar));
          else
            RegCheck(Status);
          end;
        end;
    finally
      RegCloseKey(Key);
    end;
  end;

  procedure GetOverlayIconInfo(const AOverlayHandlerCLSID: TCLSID; out AIconFileName: UnicodeString; out AIconIndex: Integer);
  var
    Unknown: IUnknown;
    ShellIconOverlayIdentifier: IShellIconOverlayIdentifier;
    Flags: DWORD;
  begin
    OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(AOverlayHandlerCLSID, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IUnknown, Unknown));
    try
      OleCheck(Unknown.QueryInterface(IID_IShellIconOverlayIdentifier, ShellIconOverlayIdentifier));
      try
        SetLength(AIconFileName, MAX_PATH);
        AIconFileName[1] := #0;
        AIconIndex := 0;
        Flags := 0;
        OleCheck(ShellIconOverlayIdentifier.GetOverlayInfo(PWideChar(AIconFileName), Length(AIconFileName), AIconIndex, Flags));
        AIconFileName := PWideChar(AIconFileName);
        if Flags and ISIOI_ICONFILE <> 0 then
          begin
            if Flags and ISIOI_ICONINDEX = 0 then
              AIconIndex := 0;
          end
        else
          begin
            AIconFileName := '';
            AIconIndex := 0;
          end;
      finally
        ShellIconOverlayIdentifier := nil;
      end;
    finally
      Unknown := nil;
    end;
  end;

  function GetSystem32Dir: UnicodeString;
  begin
    SetLength(Result, MAX_PATH);
    OleCheck(SHGetFolderPathW(0, CSIDL_SYSTEM, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, PWideChar(Result)));
    Result := PWideChar(Result) + '\';
  end;

var
  FileInfo: TSHFileInfoW;
  OverlayIconIndex: Integer;
  Key: HKEY;
  Index: Integer;
  SubKeyName: UnicodeString;
  CLSID: TCLSID;
begin
  AIconFileName := '';
  AIconIndex := 0;

  // first off all we get overlay icon index of file
  ZeroMemory(@FileInfo, SizeOf(FileInfo));
  if SHGetFileInfoW(PWideChar(AFileName), 0, FileInfo, SizeOf(FileInfo), SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX or SHGFI_ICON) = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  DestroyIcon(FileInfo.hIcon);
  OverlayIconIndex := (FileInfo.iIcon shr 24) and $0000000F;

  // now we enum all overlay icon handlers in the system
  if RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, PWideChar(sShellIconOverlayIdentifiers), 0, KEY_READ, Key) = ERROR_SUCCESS then
    try
      Index := 0;
      while True do
        begin
          SubKeyName := GetNextOverlayIconHandlerName(Key, Index);
          if SubKeyName = '' then Break;

          try
            // create an instance of current overlay icon handler
            CLSID := GetOverlayIconHandlerCLSID(Key, SubKeyName);
            // and get information about overlay icon implemented by current overlay icon handler
            GetOverlayIconInfo(CLSID, AIconFileName, AIconIndex);
            // is our overlay icon implemented by current overlay icon handler?
            // if yes we found all information we are looking for
            if SHGetIconOverlayIndexW(PWideChar(AIconFileName), AIconIndex) = OverlayIconIndex then
              Exit;
          except
          end;

          Inc(Index);
        end;
    finally
      RegCloseKey(Key);
    end;

  // our overlay icon is not implemented by any of overlay icon handler
  // lets use heuristic
  AIconFileName := '';
  AIconIndex := 0;
  // I AM NOT FULLY SURE!!!
  case OverlayIconIndex of
    1: // share overlay
      begin
        if IsWindowsVistaOrLater then
          begin
            AIconFileName := GetSystem32Dir + sImageres;
            AIconIndex := 164;
          end
        else
          begin
            AIconFileName := GetSystem32Dir + sShell32;
            AIconIndex := 29;
          end;
      end;
    2: // link overlay
      begin
        if IsWindowsVistaOrLater then
          begin
            AIconFileName := GetSystem32Dir + sImageres;
            AIconIndex := 163;
          end
        else
          begin
            AIconFileName := GetSystem32Dir + sShell32;
            AIconIndex := 30;
          end;
      end;
    3: // default overlay
      begin
        if IsWindowsVistaOrLater then
          begin
            AIconFileName := GetSystem32Dir + sImageres;
            AIconIndex := 157;
          end
      end;
    4: // slow overlay
      begin
        if IsWindowsVistaOrLater then
          begin
            AIconFileName := GetSystem32Dir + sImageres;
            AIconIndex := 169; // NOT SURE!!!
          end
        else
          begin
            AIconFileName := GetSystem32Dir + sShell32;
            AIconIndex := 31;
          end;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If this is a solution could you please explain the basics of what it's doing, as it's 200 lines long. I would like to port it into a more manageable language for my devenv.

Comment: I added some comments in the answer.